# Generate TTF from PNG/SVG files using FontForge

Tags: python, svg, truetype, fontforge

I'm trying to generate a ttf font file from a bunch of SVGs or PNGs. Every time I try, I get the error:

"Warning: Font contained no glyphs"

I've tried this on Mac and Linux:

```
font = fontforge.font()
glyph = font.createChar(65, "font1")
glyph.importOutlines("1.png")
glyph2 = font.createChar(66, "font2")
glyph2.importOutlines("2.png")
glyph3 = font.createChar(67, "font3")
glyph3.importOutlines("3.png")
font.generate("output.ttf")
```

I tried the hints on:
[Import a sequence of .svg files into FontForge as glyphs and output a font file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124130/import-a-sequence-of-svg-files-into-fontforge-as-glyphs-and-output-a-font-file/22135233#22135233)

but still couldn't get it to work.

If anyone has any ideas on a better library I can call from commmandline to convert SVG to TTF, that would be great.

Comment: An update on this... it works with .svg files but not with .png. Any idea?

Comment: because ttf font use vector graphics. you need to vecotrize your png's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType

how to make a vector from png http://goinkscape.com/how-to-vectorize-in-inkscape/